# Is there a difference between the "maximum probability" and the "mode" of a parameter?

Tags: bayesian, estimation

I am reading a manuscript that provides the "maximum posterior probability" in a Bayesian context as a statistical summary of a parameter.

Is the term "maximum posterior probability" equivalent to (i.e., "exchangeable" with) "posterior mode"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the (now edited) question is **no**, there is no difference: maximum posterior probability for a given value $\hat{\theta}_{MAP}$ (the so-called *maximum a-posteriori estimate* of $\theta$) is equivalent to the mode of the posterior distribution of your parameter. Mathematically, you can express this in the context of parameter estimation as

$$\hat{\theta}_{MAP}=\text{argmax}_{\theta}\ \ p(\theta|D,I),$$

where $p(\theta|D,I)$ is the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given the data $D$ and any information $I$ (e.g. your prior). As some people stated on the comments of the other answers **this is not equivalent to the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) in general** (this is the case if you have an uniform prior, as long as this prior is defined on a suitable interval around the MLE), because

$$p(\theta|D,I)=\frac{p(D|\theta,I)p(\theta|I)}{p(D|I)},$$

and you wish to maximize $p(D|\theta,I)p(\theta|I)$ in order to obtain the MAP estimate. On the other hand, the MLE maximizes $p(D|\theta,I)$ only.