# Inferences with Filtered and Smoothed state estimates from a tracking problem

Tags: time-series, inference, gaussian-process, kalman-filter, smoothing

I am working on a synthetic tracking problem in a two-dimensional space, where the start and end positions are known and noisy measurements of the state variables are given at discrete time steps. As a first filtering step, I am using the Kalman Filter initialized with a very small P and my known start state. Subsequently, the obtained set of a posteriori and a priori states are used in an RTS smoother to obtain smoothed state estimates, which appears to be working well so far.

Here is an example of the type of process I am tracking.
[image: Simulated Process and Filtering]

The red line represents the ground truth, while my Kalman Filter state estimates are plotted in green.

Now, my goal is to make inferences about the observed process using the smoothed state estimates (X_smooth) and their associated covariance matrices (P_smooth). For example, I would like to calculate the probability that the tracked real process was within a certain area at any given point in time based on my state estimations or determine the probability that the speed of the vehicle was above a certain threshold at any point during the process. What approaches can be used for this?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, as I have been searching for quite some time for a potential solution and feel like there has to be some way to achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this should be relatively easy. E.g., for your first example ("probability that the tracked real process was within a certain area at any given point in time"), you are interested in (assuming a rectangular region for simplicity here, but that's not necessary)
$$P(x_a \leq x \leq x_b, y_a \leq y \leq y_b | \text{ data }) = \int_{x_a}^{x_b}\int_{y_a}^{y_b} p(x, y | \text{ data }) \,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x. $$

Your RTS gives you a (multivariate normal) estimate of the density you're integrating over, so this can be quite trivially computed. Your second example works very similarly.

*However* (!) this will very likely give you extremely poor uncertainty estimates. The issue is that you are assuming a very restrictive and probably wrong process + noise model, and this will strongly affect the uncertainty estimates. (This is not / not so much an issue as long as one is not interested in uncertainty quantification and only in the estimated trajectory.)

Proper state uncertainty quantification (UQ) is fundamentally just really hard. Notice that with this you're asking for a full *distribution* to be estimated correctly, whereas if you're only interested in the most likely point, it's just that - a single point.

Generally, if you're interested in good UQ, you'll have to invest a lot more work into finding a model that *really* describes your application correctly. (--> Carefully verify the correctness of every single modeling assumption you're making.) [That may mean going to nonlinear / non-Gaussian models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01235). At the *very* least, you should consider [fitting your covariance matrices to the data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/581136/131402), instead of tuning them manually.

Now *if* your states are actually directly measurable (with noise), then you could do some kind of post-hoc uncertainty calibration. This would mean fitting a more accurate uncertainty model on some hold-out dataset. See, e.g., [[1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9330317/), [[2]](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-reliability-diagrams-for-probability-calibration-ed785b3f5d44), [[3]](https://uncertainty-toolbox.github.io/), [[4]](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v121/laves20a/laves20a.pdf). In a nutshell, you would fit a model that maps from estimated state uncertainties to actual state uncertainties. Again, this is only possible if your states are directly measured. (Somewhat surprisingly, I was unable to find references doing something like this in the Kalman filter setting. Probably I did not look for the right keywords; this seems like a very natural thing to do.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Regarding the computation of probability, when you mentioned that "RTS gives you a (multivariate normal) estimate of the density you're integrating over," I understand that you are referring to a single state estimate at a specific time. If that's the case, I might have expressed my question unclearly. My interest lies in determining the probability that the process, at any point throughout its duration, was within a certain area. I am not seeking the probability of the process being within the area at a specific time point.